# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind'

Tags: python, bash

This is my code:

```
with open (basefile,"r") as file:

    for servers in file.read().splitlines():

      rsltfile = servers+"_SNMPCHECK_RSLT.txt"

      command = (["snmp-check","-c"],["community.txt"],servers,[">>"],rsltfile)

      with open(rsltfile,"w") as rslt:

        subprocess.call(command)
```

And this is the Traceback for it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

I couldn't paste every line in the Traceback because it kept giving me errors. But anyway I can't seem to use the call method and I get this error and I don't know what is happening.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your traceback here?

Comment: And please search your code for `rfind` may some misspelling happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use a nested list/tuple.
2. `>>` is a shell feature, which in my tests doesn't seem to work, even with `shell = True`. It might work if your command was a string instead of a list, but that's not ideal either.

```
command = ["snmp-check","-c","community.txt",servers]
with open(rsltfile,"a") as rslt:  # note the "a"
    subprocess.call(command, stdout=rslt)
```

Comment: With `shell=True`, you would want a single string as an argument, not a list. For example, and ignoring defensive quoting, `call(f"snmp-check -c community.txt {servers} >> {rsltfile}", shell=True)`.

Comment: @chepner right, but you don't really want to ignore the quoting issue, hence I stuck to a list method.

Comment: Absolutely. I was just mentioning why you might not have seen `>>` to work, if you were testing with lists and `shell=True`.